# Error: [search.hbs] Missing helper: "providers"

Tags: express, handlebars.js

The code below throws the following error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> Error: [search.hbs] Missing helper: "providers"
>       at String. (/Users/me/cs-conn/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/helpers/helper-missing.js:19:13)

**in app.js**

```
import hbs from 'express-hbs';
import routes from './routes';
const app = express();
const addon = ace(app);
const viewsDir = __dirname + '/views';
app.engine('hbs', hbs.express4({partialsDir: viewsDir}));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', viewsDir);

routes(app, addon);

hbs.registerHelper('providers', function(object) {

  console.log("== " +  JSON.stringify(object))
  var result =""

  if (object === undefined){

  } else { 
    result = object.providers
    }
  console.log("\nresult\n" + result)
  return result
});

// Boot the HTTP server
http.createServer(app).listen(port, () => {
  console.log('App server running at http://' + os.hostname() + ':' + port);

  // Enables auto registration/de-registration of app into a host in dev mode
  if (devEnv) addon.register();
});
```

**hbs template**

```html
{{#if search_results includeZero=true}}
    <div>
    {{#each meta_results.indices_original}}
   
        <a href="/search?search={{../search_criteria}}&indexname={{@key}}&providers={{{providers ../meta_results}}}&indices_original={{{all_indices ../meta_results}}}"> Search only {{this}} </a><br>
    {{/each}}
    </div>
{{/if}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your question is self explanatory : the provider helper is not found.
I think that your declaration of helper is not correct. You may find help on this post :
[Node / Express Handlebars - Where to define custom helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661295/node-express-handlebars-where-to-define-custom-helpers)

Comment: It does not explian why it cannot be found. And app.js is a legitimate deployment place. That said, your link is helpful, tks